# bussproofs.sty single longer line?

Tags: logic, proof-package, bussproofs, ebproof

How would I write a line that is longer than the formula, even when the next formula is the same size, so that the line is apparently longer. For example, I want to write:

```
a
--
b
--
c
----
a
--
c
```

However, the best I could do was use an empty formula with 3 `\quad`'s and use `\vspace`, but the `\vspace` seemed to have no effect, no matter where I put it in the proof tree - in the braces, or outside them. Changing `\vspace` size also did not help. The code I wrote is:

```
\begin{prooftree}
    \AXC{ $ A $ }
    \UIC{ $ B $ }
    \UIC{ $ C $ }
    \UIC{ $ \quad\quad\quad $ }
    \vspace{-1em} 
    \UIC{ $ A $ }
    \UIC{ $ C $ }
\end{prooftree}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community. Please, can you put a minimal working example of your full code in tex and a sketch? Thank you.

Comment: As written, your code doesn't compile even when a topper and end is added because `\AXC`, `\UIC` aren't defined by `bussproofs`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what format you want or what your code does. Assuming that `\AXC` and `\UIC` are defined as `\AxiomC` and `\UnaryInfC` respectively, you might be looking for something like this

[image: possible target format]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{prooftree}
    \AxiomC{ $ A $ }
    \UnaryInfC{ $ B $ }
    \UnaryInfC{ $ C $ }
    \AxiomC{  }
    \BinaryInfC{ $ A $ }
    \UnaryInfC{ $ C $ }
  \end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```